# not able to remove message from jms activemq queue

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, jmstemplate

i am new to `jms` technology. I am using `activeMQ` console for monitoring queues. I am able create queue with message in it. But when I try to remove certain queue.. a exception is coming. Tried many things, but all in vein.. below is my code:

**code**

```
   BrokerService brokerService = new BrokerService();
        try {
            brokerService.start(true);
            brokerService.start();
            brokerService.autoStart();
            brokerService.setUseJmx(true);
            brokerService.addConnector("tcp://localhost:61616");
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            System.out.println("brokerService : "+brokerService.isStarted());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        BrokerFacadeSupport facade=   new LocalBrokerFacade(brokerService);
        try {
            QueueViewMBean queue = facade.getQueue(queue_name);
            if(queue==null) {
                System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            }
                    int count = this.jmsTemplate.browse(queue_name, new BrowserCallback<Integer>() {
                public Integer doInJms(final Session session, final QueueBrowser browser) throws JMSException {
                    Queue queue1 = browser.getQueue();
                    Enumeration enumeration = browser.getEnumeration();
                    int counter = 0;
                    while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
                        Message msg = (Message) enumeration.nextElement();
                        msg.acknowledge();
                        ActiveMQTextMessage atm  = (ActiveMQTextMessage) msg;
                        atm.setDroppable(true);
                        atm.setReadOnlyProperties(false);
                        atm.setReadOnlyBody(false);
                        atm.acknowledge();
                        msg.setBooleanProperty("readOnlyProperties", false);
                                    msg.setBooleanProperty("readOnlyBody", false);
                                    msg.setBooleanProperty("droppable", true);
                        Enumeration enum_ = atm.getPropertyNames();
                        while(enum_.hasMoreElements()) {
                            String name  = (String) enum_.nextElement();
                            System.out.println("## : "+name);
                        }
                        try {
                            System.out.println("--"+atm.getJMSMessageID());
                            System.out.println();
                            queue.removeMessage(atm.getJMSMessageID());
                        }catch(Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        System.out.println(String.format("\tFound : %s", msg));
                        counter += 1;
                    }
                    return counter;
                }
            });
            queue.purge();
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**output**

output to `System.out.println(String.format("\tFound : %s", msg));` is :

```
Found : ActiveMQTextMessage {commandId = 5, responseRequired = true, messageId = ID:CRM-PC-50101-1528866712471-1:1:1:1:1, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = ID:CRM-PC-50101-1528866712471-1:1:1:1, destination = queue://testNexus, transactionId = null, expiration = 0, timestamp = 1528866713408, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 1528866713410, brokerOutTime = 1529047482640, correlationId = null, replyTo = null, persistent = true, type = null, priority = 4, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@12b82970, marshalledProperties = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@49abe550, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 0, properties = {_type=com.crm.jms.SampleObject}, readOnlyProperties = true, readOnlyBody = true, droppable = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false, text = {"msg":"hello world"}}
```

**final output console**

```
==>   _type : com.crm.jms.SampleObject
--ID:Crm-PC-50101-1528866712471-1:1:1:1:1
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.crm.jms.controller.QueueController$1.doInJms(QueueController.java:171)
    at com.crm.jms.controller.QueueController$1.doInJms(QueueController.java:1)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate$14.doInJms(JmsTemplate.java:1033)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:484)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.browseSelected(JmsTemplate.java:1027)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.browse(JmsTemplate.java:989)
    at com.crm.jms.controller.QueueController.deleteQueue(QueueController.java:153)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
.
.
.
.
    Found : ActiveMQTextMessage {commandId = 5, responseRequired = true, messageId = ID:Crm-PC-50101-1528866712471-1:1:1:1:1, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = ID:Crm-PC-50101-1528866712471-1:1:1:1, destination = queue://testNexus, transactionId = null, expiration = 0, timestamp = 1528866713408, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 1528866713410, brokerOutTime = 1529049245130, correlationId = null, replyTo = null, persistent = true, type = null, priority = 4, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@5b55f70f, marshalledProperties = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@3e116ae6, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 0, properties = {_type=com.crm.jms.SampleObject}, readOnlyProperties = true, readOnlyBody = true, droppable = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false, text = {"msg":"hello world"}}
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.crm.jms.controller.QueueController.deleteQueue(QueueController.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: It is impossible to correlate the stack-trace with the code you've pasted without line numbers.  It would also help to have the entire com.crm.jms.controller.QueueController class to make more sense of the stack-trace.

Comment: you see the problem I am getting is in this line: `QueueViewMBean queue = facade.getQueue(queueName);` ... here queue is `null`, so whether I call `removeMessage` or `purge` method, all giving `null pointer exception`.

Comment: Could you share QueueController class? A git also helps

Answer (score 3):

Why do you acknowledge messages that you are **browsing** (and not **consuming**) ?

```
Enumeration enumeration = browser.getEnumeration();
...
Message msg = (Message) enumeration.nextElement();
msg.acknowledge();
```

As you noticed it, there is indeed no delete()/remove() method on javax.jms.Queue, but you can maybe reach the same results by just consuming the desired messages (still using the pure JMS API):

```
MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(myQueue, "JMSMessageID = '" + messageId + "'");
Message message = consumer.receive(TIMEOUT);
message.acknowledge();
```

Comment: you see the problem I am getting is in this line: `QueueViewMBean queue = facade.getQueue(queueName);` ... here queue is `null`, so whether I call `removeMessage` or `purge` method, all giving `null pointer exception`.

Comment: And which value has your 'queueName' variable ?

Comment: That's exactly the point: what is the actual value of queueName when entering the method ? A wrong value may be the reason why the queue is not found. In particular the exact queueName required by the JMS api (eg session.createConsumer) might be different from the one required by the native ActiveMQ api (eg facade.getQueue). For instance: "queue/myqueue" vs "myqueue"

Comment: see, I am able to get message id from that `queueName`.. then I wanted to delete that message from given queue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not starting an `BrokerService` so the `facade.getQueue(queueName)` method will return `null`. Why? Because facade object don't know which active mq server you are asking for.

Of course you are getting some information about your message because you are connecting with an `jmsTemplate` to an running broker server.

Exceptions are thrown on `queue.purge();` and `queue.removeMessage(msg.getJMSMessageID());` because `queue` is `null`.

I would suggest removing the `BrokerService` and `BrokerServiceFacade` stuff and get the `Queue` object inside the callback by `browser.getQueue()` method from `QueueBrowser` argument.

Comment: Ok, but `browser.getQueue()` object i.e. `javax.jms.Queue` does not have remove method available..

Comment: also `brokerService.start()` has started the brokerService but `queue` is still null

Comment: Did you start the broker with `broker.setUseJmx(true)` and `broker.addConnector("tcp://localhost:PORT");` ? Because without specified `url` the broker will start withing your JVM.

Comment: sorry, friend, its still not initializing queue..Queue object is still `null` Anyways I have updated my question with all corrections that you made me to do..please, review/approve the code above to see if I have made it right..thanks for your efforts.